# Meta service adds tags twice (once for / and once for the current route)

Tags: angular, universal

Current behavior

I am using Meta service right now in an Angular 4 Universal application. So I add a few meta tags on the home component (route /) and the same ones with different values on another page (some route /abc). Now if I go to route /, i only see the meta tags for that page, but if i go to any other route, I see the meta tags for route / followed by css styles, followed by meta tags for the page I am currently on. This is on server side and client side both.

I have tried using forceCreation, updateTags and every other thing possible. Unable to solve.

Expected behavior

Meta tags should only be shown for current page.

Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

Try this out on https://www.thepixelatedplanet.com. View page source for the landing page and then navigate to workshops and view page source for that. See the 2 blocks of meta tags with different values.

**UPDATE**

Code repro - 2 components with routes as follows -

```
/ -> HomeComponent
/workshops -> WorkshopComponent
```

In HomeComponent,

```
constructor(meta:Meta) {
 meta.addTags([
        { name: 'twitter:title', content: 'Home Page' },
        { property: 'og:title', content: 'Home Page' }
      ]);
}
```

In WorkshopComponent,

```
constructor(meta:Meta) {
 meta.addTags([
        { name: 'twitter:title', content: 'Workshop Page' },
        { property: 'og:title', content: 'Workshop Page' }
      ]);
}
```

**So the issue is that on home page, all is good, I see only 2 meta tags for that page. But on workshops page source, I see both the home page meta tags and then both meta tags from the workshops page separated by all the styles.**

Comment: Please provide the code that allows to reproduce. In addition a https://stackblitz.com/ would be very helpful as well.

Comment: I guess you need to remove the added tag in `ngOnDestroy()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I do have that as well. This still happens. Head tag has meta tags for / and the actual route

Comment: A https://stackblitz.com/ or Plunker to reproduce would be handy.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried creating a stackblitz but apparently it doesn't work with angular universal. I tried prerender with express, but doesn't render server side. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edpcxu

Comment: Sorry, I missed the universal part. You could try a bug report.